# Expected value and Variance question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, dice, expected-value

[image]

So let $A$ be the event the die falls either "one", "two", or "three"

Let $B$ be the event the die falls either "four" or "five"

and let $C$ be the event the die falls "six"

$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$,
$P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$,
$P(C) = \frac{1}{6}$

So since $X$ is the amount Betty receives, to find $E(X)$...

$E(X) = \frac{1}{2} * 2 + \frac{1}{3} * 3 + \frac{1}{6} * 6 = 3$

and to find the variance:

$var(x) = (2-3)^{2} * \frac{1}{2} + (3-3)^{2} * \frac{1}{3} + (6-3)^{2} * \frac{1}{6} = 2$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: I would argue that this is not discrete mathematics

Comment: The tag for `discrete-mathematics` says "The study of discrete mathematical structures. Consider using a more specific tag instead, such as: (combinatorics), (graph-theory), (computer-science), (probability), (elementary-set-theory), (induction), (recurrence-relations), etc.". This question mixes combinatorics and probability, maybe some elementary set theory.

Comment: But also, your solution is correct :) -- I suggest you post an answer stating this, then accept that answer, to remove it from the 'unanswered' section